# How many speech sounds (phonemes) are there in English?

Tags: phonemes, phonics

Is the following statement correct especially the section about there being 44 individual speech sounds as I'm thinking there's actually a lot more sounds than that?

"English words are produced using a combination of 44 individual speech sounds called 'phonemes'. These phonemes can be represented in writing using the 26 letters of the English alphabet, either individually or combined with other letters. There are numerous spelling choices (graphemes) for each phoneme."

Comment: They are referring to [phonemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme), which isn't the same as sounds. Maybe what you are referring to by sounds is [phones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_(phonetics)).

Comment: How many phonemes there are in English depends on which variety of it you speak. The number 44 comes from 20th-century Received Pronunciation (as could be heard on the BBC).

Comment: Please cite and link to the quote, if quoted from a published source.